# Why isn't my python discord command working?

Tags: python, discord.py

As you can see, it is a mute command, with the `role` method.
When I tried to execute it, nothing happened, and there isn't any error in the output.

I have tried to search for syntax errors, but i didn't find any.

```py
    @commands.command() #mute
    @commands.has_permissions(mute_members=True)
    async def mute(self, ctx, user : discord.Member, time: int):
        rolem = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name='Muted')

        if rolem not in user.roles:
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.name} sikeresen némítva {time} másodpercre.', color=0x00ff00)
            embed.add_field(name="Pssszzz!", value=":zipper_mouth:")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await user.add_roles(rolem)
            await sleep(time)
        elif rolem in user.roles:
                try:
                    await user.remove_roles(rolem)
                    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.name} -ról/ről automatikusan levettem a némítást.', color=0x00ff00)
                    embed.add_field(name="Újra beszélhetsz!", value=":open_mouth:")
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                except Exception:
                    pass
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} már némítva van.')
```

Comment: use `print()` to debug your code.

Comment: Do you have other working commands?  If not, do you have an `on_message` event?  Are you sure the cog is being loaded correctly?

Comment: Yes, the cog is sucessfully loaded, and in this cog the other commands working beside that.